# Checking if all the array items are empty PHP

Tags: php, arrays, validation

I'm adding an array of items from a form and if all of them are empty, I want to perform some validation and add to an error string. So I have:

```
$array = array(
    'RequestID'       => $_POST["RequestID"],
    'ClientName'      => $_POST["ClientName"],
    'Username'        => $_POST["Username"],
    'RequestAssignee' => $_POST["RequestAssignee"],
    'Status'          => $_POST["Status"],
    'Priority'        => $_POST["Priority"]
);
```

And then if all of the array elements are empty perform:

```
$error_str .= '<li>Please enter a value into at least one of the fields regarding the request you are searching for.</li>';
```

Answer (score 211, accepted):

You can just use the built in [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.

So can do this in one simple line.

```
if(!array_filter($array)) {
    echo '<li>Please enter a value into at least one of the fields regarding the request you are searching for.</li>';
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know if this is faster than the implode method I suggested. Any benchmark around?

Comment: `array_filter()` was already mentioned by @dogmatic69. About performance - I believe simple `foreach` should be faster than both `array_filter()` and `implode()`.

Comment: Here is a great sight for php benchmarks of built in functions http://www.phpbench.com/ but presumably it would depend on the size of the array. The larger the array the fast this method would be.

Comment: The implode method could be more efficient by removing the call to strlen. `if(implode($array)) echo '..'`

Comment: `could be more efficient` OMFG!

Comment: Foreach construct will always be slower because it is in essence doing the same thing as `array_filter` but in userland. Looping in userland cannot be as fast as the looping in the internal methods. Although depending on the function of the loop and the interpreter may be able to optimize it at compile time to an `array_filter` or similar.

Comment: @xzyfer, `if(implode($array)) echo '..'` would print '..' even if one array element would be `(string)"0"`. About `foreach` being slower than `array_filter()` - are you sure? How is removing array elements one-by-one faster than just reading array elements?

Comment: @binaryLV, you're correct about about the implode, the point was I was trying to make was that `strlen` was a heavy function to call simply to know if there was anything in the string. It would also fail that test for that matter. `trim` would have been a better options. Regarding the foreach, the fact is that at compile time the foreach cannot always (if ever) be optimised by the interpreter. You can always (barring some edge cases that escape memory) rely on a native functions internal loop to be faster than a user defined one. At best it will be converted to a native equilavent if possible.

Comment: @xzyfer, I did some tests - using `array_filter()` just to check if any value is filled is at least *few times* slower than basic `foreach` loop with some boolean variable for storing result and `break` on first invalid value. Even with `array_filter()` being a "native PHP function", it can't really be faster than `foreach` as it has to create new array variable.

Comment: @xzyfer, `strlen()` indeed is not the best way to find out if string variable is filled, though `if ( strlen($str) === 0 )` and `if ( !$str )` are different conditions, as `strlen('0') === 0` would be `false`, while `!'0'` would be `true`. In most cases, it's better to do `if ( $str === '' )`.

Comment: @binaryLV, you are correct that there would be an edge case if the resulting string only contained '0' or ' ', regarding the boolean evaluation.

Comment: @xzyfer, `(bool)' '` evaluates to `true`. The only exception is `'0'`, though it's enough with this single exception to avoid using `if ( $str ) { }`.

Comment: @binaryLV, correct again. Although I disagree with boycotting `if ( $str )`. It's an edge case, and in most scenarios an unlikely one. You usually use it safely as long as you're aware of the context. IMHO.

Comment: i upvoted, still i am a bit surprised this was actually accepted, because it does not fullfill the requirement, does it?  If you put say, `requestID=0` and `status=0` this will result in "please enter a value" when there were clearly values.

Answer (score 26):

Implode the array with an empty glue and check the size of the resulting string:

```
<?php if (strlen(implode($array)) == 0) echo 'all values of $array are empty'; ?>
```

> Please note this is a safe way to consider values like `0` or `"0"` as not empty. The accepted answer using an empty `array_filter` callback will consider such values empty, as it uses the [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function. Many form usages would have to consider `0` as valid answers so be careful when choosing which method works best for you.

Comment: YOu could remove the `strlen` call to make this more efficient. `if(implode($array)) echo '..'`

Comment: @binaryLV, how so? Agreed they both fail to solve the problem. But they are inequivalent are they not?

Comment: @xzyfer, if `$str` is `(string)'0'`, then `strlen($str) == 0` evaluates to `false`, while `!$str` evaulates to `true`, therefore `strlen($str) == 0` can't be replaced with `!$str`.

Comment: This solution feels more correct opposed to using `array_filter`, because `array_filter` is intended to be used with a callback, you know, to *filter* an array. But all you want to do is check for 'emptiness'. So you make a string of it and check its length. Brilliant.

Comment: @kasimir the callback function of `array_filter` is optional and the manual clearly states _If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed._ So, using `array_filter` is not less correct than this, it's just a diffrent method ;-)

Comment: what if the array is having a number also according to !empty() 0 is considered as empty but according to your filter, it counts 0 as length 1

Comment: @SayedMohdAli the OP asked to test for empty items, not empty() items. For me, the value "0" is not empty. For example, the priority field could have a valid value of 0.

Comment: OP never said it will be blank he said it is empty. and according to PHP which is his tag empty is blank, 0 or null. Status can be integer value 0(false) or 1(true). but according to your scenario, it will count it as always true...  either the value os status is 0 or 1. In some cases any value can be a null which is also an empty.
There is nothing wrong in you answer but it needs improvement and should give a universal solution...

Comment: @SayedMohdAli I don't agree. In common language, "empty" describes an empty string. To me 0 is not empty, it's the value 0. The fact PHP considers 0 empty when using empty() is highly confusing, which is probably why I almost never used that function.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli so what? You inserted data in your DB without checking that it was a correct phone number. You shouldn't check back that what is already in your DB is wrong (btw a phone number is not an int as it can have leading zeros). Here's another one: Let's say one of your fields is the number of children you have. 0 is a valid answer and shouldn't be rejected. If you use `empty()` it will be, and you won't be able to submit a valid answer.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli I don't think we speak the same language. Re-read my comments. I know about data types, DBs, default values and how the empty() function work. Heck, I've been using them for 20 years and people have paid me to do so, but when I started I listened a lot to what others had to say. Maybe you should do the same instead of thinking you know better than anybody else.

Comment: @Capsule you are working from 20 years on the language PHP and you are saying the one who made PHP and empty() functions are fool and wrong but you are right because you are working on it since 20 years... this is not something a good answer, to prove your point.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli no, I'm saying `empty()` is not suitable for this question in case you want to keep the values "0" in a form. Ditto.

Comment: Btw this is a comment that has already be made in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040811/checking-if-all-the-array-items-are-empty-php/5040899?noredirect=1#comment84399181_38447764 Feel free to tell @mickmackusa is wrong too while you're at it.

Comment: @Capsule you answer is good and I appreciate it but the thing is OP never said what is empty in his case. and you can improve your answer quality if you can give an alternative solution and in your answer if you describe that it will not work with 0

Comment: Since the OP provided no sample data and no specific description of what "empty" means and because this page is being used as a canonical, answers should be very careful to provide robust explanations and include caveats where their answers may provide unexpected results.  `array_filter()` and `empty()` are too often misused/misunderstood by php developers.

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks for your comment, I added a note to my answer reflecting that.

Answer (score 9):

An older question but thought I'd pop in my solution as it hasn't been listed above.

```
function isArrayEmpty(array $array): bool {
    foreach($array as $key => $val) {
        if ($val !== '' && $val !== null) // remove null check if you only want to check for empty strings
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `empty()` may provide false-positive results.  See the manual about how the function treats `falsey` values.  I would recommend the call of `strlen()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about falseyness @mickmackusa, I've updated it to explicity check for empty string.

Answer (score 3):

you don't really need it.
You're going to validate these fields separately and by finishing this process you can tell if array was empty (or contains invalid values, which is the same)

Comment: interesting! I wonder if this is faster than imploding the array.

Comment: @Capsule for the array size of 6, you will never ever see the slightest difference, even you spend whole your life checking arrays. for the sizes more than 1000 I'd suggest not to use arrays at all.

Comment: Since we are talking about websites, you have to multiply that per your number of visitors. An array of 1000 or 100 visitors computing an array of 10 is the same in term of CPU cost. You can't decide to stop using arrays because your website is gaining some popularity ;-)

Answer (score 3):

simplify use this way:

```
$array = []; //target array
$is_empty = true; //flag

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != '')
        $is_empty = false;
}
if ($is_empty)
    echo 'array is empty!';
else
    echo 'array is not empty!';
```

Comment: We should see a `break` in this script.  Your answer is missing its educational explanation.  This is effectively the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/38447764/2943403 but a worse version.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question but wanted to check each element in the array separately to see which one was empty.  This was harder than expected as you need to create the key values and the actual values in separate arrays to check and respond to the empty array element.

```
print_r($requestDecoded);
$arrayValues = array_values($requestDecoded);  //Create array of values
$arrayKeys = array_keys($requestDecoded);      //Create array of keys to count
$count = count($arrayKeys);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){  
    if ( empty ($arrayValues[$i] ) ) {         //Check which value is empty
        echo $arrayKeys[$i]. " can't be empty.\r\n";
    } 
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [PONumber] => F12345
    [CompanyName] => Test
    [CompanyNum] => 222222
    [ProductName] => Test
    [Quantity] =>
    [Manufacturer] => Test
)
```

Quantity can't be empty.

Comment: what? Just use `foreach($array as $key => $value)` and test if `$value` is empty of not.

Answer (score -4):

this is pretty simple:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v)
{
    if(empty($v))
    {
        unset($array[$k]);
    }
}
$show_error = count($array) == 0;
```

you would also have to change your encapsulation for your array values to double quotes.

Comment: He doesn't need a number. Just 1 is enough

Comment: What?, He wanted to know if *all* the elements are empty, there is no number just a boolean

Comment: I think what Col. is crassly saying is that in PHP both `count($array) == 0` and `count($array)` evaluate to true so the extra comparison and assignment steps are unnecessary overheard. Although assignments cost very little in php.

Comment: Ahhh yea, it does not really make a huge difference but I would rather work with boolean's most of the time, I don't get why the down votes though, its a working method and creates him the result required.

Comment: to say if an array is empty or not, it is enough to find only ONE filled element. it is called LOGIC.

Comment: Correct it works, and gives the required results. But IMHO it's an ugly implementation, especially when there is a native method to do it. Also, using `unset` on the subject of a `foreach` in the `foreach` is bad practice, although in this case it won't cause a problem because you're only destroying the current element. Because of those things, it's a bad influence on beginners. More so coming from someone of your high reputation.

Comment: That's given, but the OP didn't require the performance to be a factor in this, if he did then the question would of been a little different, the code shows the principles of looping through the array, checking the status of each element and modifying accordingly to predict a new result, on such a small array, the unset would have minute effect on performance, I personally think that the down voters are attention seeking because they think they have found a flaw, when really there is no floor what so ever and the answer is what the op had requested, therefore the down votes was out of context.

Comment: Sorry for the late bashing but I'm joining @xzyfer on this one. `unset()` on the array being "foreached()" should definitely be avoided and `empty()` is generally bad practice since `empty(0)` or `empty('0')` are both true. In this question, `$_POST["Priority"]` could be set to 0 (it's a priority, 0 could be valid) and would trigger an error.