# PHP validate form arrays

Tags: php, arrays, validation

I have a form with inputs that can be duplicated with jQuery. The inputs are like this

```
<select name='user_id[]'>
    <option value=''>Select a user</option>
    <option value='1'>Alice</option>
    <option value='2'>Bob</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="drinks1" name="drinks[]" />
<input type="text" id="drinks2" name="drinks[]" />
<input type="text" id="food1" name="food[]" />
<input type="text" id="food2" name="food[]" />
```

So in my processing script I have the arrays `$_POST['userid']`, `$_POST['drinks']` and `$_POST['food']`

How can I check if these are empty? The `empty()` function doesnt work because they look like this when I print them `Array ( [0] => )` which appears to be non-empty.

Comment: Use var_dump on POST, it may help you understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply loop through the array to check if any field is empty:

```
foreach($_POST['userid'] as $key=>$value) if(empty($value)) echo "empty";
```

You can do the same with all your arrays.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't need to loop through the arrays. I found that `!array_filter($array)` does the job as well. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040811/checking-if-all-the-array-items-are-empty-php)