# check if array row is empty

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array that I've imported from a csv. But the last line on the csv is epmty, yet it still imports the empty values into the array.

Is there an easy way to check if an entire row is empty within an array?

Here's the code I'm using (I'm checking the array against the contents of another array to build a mySQL statement:

```
foreach (array_keys($array[0]) as $arraykey => $dbtitles){
            foreach ($fields as $dbkey => $dbfield){
                if ($dbtitles == $dbfield && !empty($arraykey) ){
                    $insertSQL .= "student_" . $dbkey . ", ";
                }
            }
        }
```

Apologies if I'm being stupid.

Here's the last part of my array:

```
[21] => Array
    (
        [Username] => 
        [Last_Name] => Jones
        [First_Name] => Tom
        [Email] => 
        [Password] => password
        [Student_Id] => 
        [Middle_Name] => 
        [Job_Title] => 
        [Department] => 
        [Company] => 
        [Street_1] => 21 A Road
        [Street_2] => 
        [City] => Exeter
        [County] => 
        [Postcode] => EX1 1AA
        [Country] => 
        [Work_Phone] => 
        [Home_Phone] => 
        [Work_Fax] => 
        [Mobile_Phone] => 07111 222333
        [Website] => 
        [Role] => Exeter City
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [Username] => 
        [Last_Name] => 
        [First_Name] => 
        [Email] => 
        [Password] => 
        [Student_Id] => 
        [Middle_Name] => 
        [Job_Title] => 
        [Department] => 
        [Company] => 
        [Street_1] => 
        [Street_2] => 
        [City] => 
        [County] => 
        [Postcode] => 
        [Country] => 
        [Work_Phone] => 
        [Home_Phone] => 
        [Work_Fax] => 
        [Mobile_Phone] => 
        [Website] => 
        [Role] => 
    )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if all the array items are empty PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040811/checking-if-all-the-array-items-are-empty-php)

Answer (score 2):

Like what's said in the duplicate, take a look at [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.

So can do this in one simple line.

```
if(!array_filter($array)) {
    // Every fields are empty, null or equal to false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Kinda. Certainly enough to continue and fix the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (array_keys($array[0]) as $arraykey => $dbtitles){
        foreach ($fields as $dbkey => $dbfield){
            if ($dbtitles == $dbfield && !empty($arraykey) ){
                $insertSQL .= "student_" . $dbkey . ", ";
            }
        }
    }
```

In your foreach you are only finding array keys for array [0], try doing it with just $array instead of $array[0]

Answer (score 0):

You should try array_pop for better solution.

```
<?php
$CSVFileLines = array_pop(file('/path/to/your/data.csv'));
foreach($CSVFileLines as $CSVLine){
$CSVLineValues = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', explode(',', $CSVLine));
$InsertSQL = sprintf("insert into tablename values ('%s')", implode("','", $CSVLineValues));
mysql_query($InsertSQL); #Depreated in All recent PHP Versions so you should use MySQLi
}
echo sprintf('There were %s lines contained in the targeted CSV.', count($CSVFileLines));
?>
```

Comment: I would use array_pop, but I need to check if any rows are empty, not just automatically remove the end row.