# if array has one item AND a value

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check for some cases, but I can't get this to work.

`$a` and `$b` have values, but I have arrays like `$c` that I do not wish to print.

How to do this?

```
$a = array("1", "2", "3");
$b = array("A"); // array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "A" }
$c = array(""); // array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

function does_have_value($arr) {
  if (!empty($arr)) {
   echo 'have value';
  }
}

does_have_value($a); // have value
does_have_value($b); // have value
does_have_value($c); // have value (but I want this to fail)
```

Comment: @u_mulder that doesn't answer my question, it's a special case, pleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaase stop closing my questions I've been fighting with this for over 2 hours now!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: That's the second time this question has been closed with the same duplicate, but it doesn't answer the question. It's not about the array being empty, it's about the *values* being empty. Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040811/checking-if-all-the-array-items-are-empty-php instead

Comment: @iainn in the first dupe there's a note "If you need to clean out empty values before checking..." so it could somehow help OP, but still I added your dupe too.

Comment: @iainn thanks, so you're saying that I have to do a loop and check if all items are empty? I thought there is a better solution than this, no?

Comment: @u_mulder that note must have been added way after, I didn't even see a note for 2 min after closing.. can you paste it here please?